# Cache acces token using Spring Oauth2

Tags: java, spring, rest, oauth, oauth2resttemplate

I have implemented REST web services in java spring framework. My application needs to acquire an Access Token in order to in order to make other URL requests. I would like to cache the token so I can reuse it until it expires. For now, I'm using a field to store the token but would there be another way using a spring-security class ?

This is how I acquire the accesToken:

```
@Bean
private OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails() {
    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails details = new 
    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    details.setClientId(clientId);
    details.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    accessTokenUrl = BackEndUrl + "/oauth2/token";
    details.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUrl);
    return details;
}

@Bean
private OAuth2RestTemplate createRestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails(), clientContext);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<String> service() {

    // Token recovery if no token has been created or if the token expiration time is exceeded
    if (this.strToken == null || this.tokenLimitTime.isBeforeNow()) {
        OAuth2ClientContext context = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();

        OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = createRestTemplate(context);

        OAuth2AccessToken token = restTemplate.getAccessToken();

        if (token != null) {
            this.strToken = token.getValue();
            this.tokenLimitTime = DateTime.now().plusSeconds(token.getExpiresIn());
        }
    }
```

Comment: what solution did you implement?

Comment: any solution that got implemented / worked?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which token store you are using. For example if you are using `InMemoryTokenStore` or `JDBCTOkenStore` there are API provided to access token using username or using client Id (i.e `public Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> findTokensByClientIdAndUserName(String clientId, String userName)` or `public Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> findTokensByClientId(String clientId)`).

If you are using JwtTokenStore there is `ApprovalStore` mechanism.

Comment: These stores appear to be for use in a Server that is OAuth protected for keeping track of tokens that have been handed out.  I think the original question is in reference to how to cache tokens on the client.